# Oracle 12c: Error when trying to create virtual Column on Json Query Result

Tags: json, oracle

I've a problem creating a virtual column on the result of a JSON_QUERY to a JSON field in my table. The funny thing is, I was able to create several such columns, but one make so big troubles, that it **makes the Oracle instance unusable**.

The JSON is saved in a column called DESCRIPTION in a table called PRODUCT and contains a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "name": "foo",
   "codes": ["A","B","C"],
   "packages": [
   {
     "number": "1234",
     "size": "small"
    },
    {
      "number": "5678",
      "size": "medium"
    }
   ]
 }
```

It is possible to query the information without any problems. E.g.

```
 SELECT JSON_QUERY(DESCRIPTION, '$.codes') FROM PRODUCT
```

returns me ["A", "B", "C"] and the command

```
 ALTER TABLE PRODUCT ADD (CODES VARCHAR2(500) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_QUERY(DESCRIPTION, '$.codes' RETURNING VARCHAR2(500))));
```

creates a column with the correct content.

But now my problem: If I try the same thing with the package numbers, the creation of the virtual column **breaks the Oracle instance - do not try this on an instance you care about**.

Querying the data works perfectly fine:

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY(DESCRIPTION, '$.packages[*].number' WITH WRAPPER) FROM PRODUCT;
```

gives me ["1234","5678"]. But trying to create a virtual column:

```
ALTER TABLE PRODUCT ADD (PACKAGE_NUMBERS VARCHAR2(500) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_QUERY(DESCRIPTION, '$.packages[*].number' WITH WRAPPER RETURNING VARCHAR2(500))));
```

returns me no error, everything looks fine, but after this command every SQL-command I send to the database is answered with:

```
Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 907
```

and the only thing I can do to resolve this is to throw the instance away and start from scratch.

Anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This sounds like something you should really be raising a service request with Oracle for.

Comment: I was unsure if I did something wrong entirely or if it is a problem in the Oracle system itself. But, thinking about it after writing it down, it sure sounds like a general problem ...

Comment: Even if you did something wrong, if it's killing wrong instance then it's still a bug IMO, and something Oracle needs to know about? It may be no-one has done exactly this before. (Or maybe it's a known problem, and there's a patch, but it still might need an SR if it isn't published. I haven't looked *8-) The exact patch level of your DB might be relevant to searching MOS).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will communicate my problem to the Oracle forum.